# How to set the value in the string if string contain key's in thymeleaf

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I am trying to set the value in string but issue is the same string containing key's..

note :- `String` content will change based on the user selection but key won't change.

```
    binder.put("ocPercent", "5");
                binder.put("ocPercentInWords", "Five");
    ${ocPercent} % (${ocPercentInWords} Percent) of the principal portion of the Receivables,

    List<ParagraphDetails> internalCredit = new ArrayList<>();

//String Content

    internalCredit.add("${ocPercent} % (${ocPercentInWords} Percent) of the principal portion of the Receivables ..etc")

binder.put("internalCredit", internalCredit);
```

in `HTML`

```
<div th:each="internalCreditEnhancement : ${internalCredit}">               
      <p><span th:text="${internalCreditEnhancement.Contents}"></span></p>
</div>
```

output comming

```
${ocPercent} % (${ocPercentInWords} Percent) of the principal portion of the Receivables ..etc
```

but expected output should be

```
5 % (Five Percent) of the principal portion of the Receivables ..etc
```

how to acheiew this concept?

Answer (score 1):

Replace `${ocPercent} % (${ocPercentInWords} Percent)` with `ocPercent +"%" ("+ocPercentInWords+" Percent)"`

You should be using string concatenation rather than expression language.

Expressions should be used in the html code.

Answer (score 1):

On your controller add the two variables on your model map (maybe you already do this)

```
modelMap.addAttribute("ocPercent", "5");
modelMap.addAttribute("ocPercentInWords", "Five");
```

Then on your html use the following th:text attribute

```
<p><span th:text="${ocPercent} + ' % (' + ${ocPercentInWords} + ' Percent) of the principal portion of the Receivables ..etc'"></span></p>
```

That way you do not need to construct the whole String on your controller, but you can only pass the variables and have the full message (without the values) in the html page.

Below is an example using ArrayList of Credit Values including percent in numbers and Words.

Credit Class:

```
public class Credit {

    private int ocPercent;
    private String ocPercentInWords;

    public int getOcPercent() {
        return ocPercent;
    }

    public void setOcPercent(int ocPercent) {
        this.ocPercent = ocPercent;
    }

    public String getOcPercentInWords() {
        return ocPercentInWords;
    }

    public void setOcPercentInWords(String ocPercentInWords) {
        this.ocPercentInWords = ocPercentInWords;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
//Creating 2 Credits 5%, 10% for testing
List<Credit> internalCredit = new ArrayList<>();
Credit a = new Credit();
a.setOcPercent(5);
a.setOcPercentInWords("Five");
Credit b = new Credit();
b.setOcPercent(10);
b.setOcPercentInWords("Ten");
internalCredit.add(a);
internalCredit.add(b);

modelMap.addAttribute("internalCredit", internalCredit);
```

Your modelMap now includes a List containing Credit objects holding both values in numbers and words.

```
<div th:each="internalCreditEnhancement : ${internalCredit}">
  <p><span th:text="${internalCreditEnhancement.ocPercent} + ' % (' + ${internalCreditEnhancement.ocPercentInWords} + ' Percent) of the principal portion of the Receivables ..etc'"></span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: @loannis Barakos  thank you for giving suggestion but i can't add static string content in html beacuse string content will change dynamically

Comment: The static content is as in your example the  '% .. Percent) of the ...' The values (5 and Five) are not static. If you want to use a List there is a way to do it using Thymeleaf practices and not Strings concatenated in controllers